# case sensitivity issue - rename a folder in git

Tags: git

I have a folder called **Utils**.

After checking it in to remote I see it appears as **utils** which fails the build.

I tried to follow renaming methods (maybe I'm doing it wrong) but I'm not able to change it.
This is what I tried.

```
git mv utils Utils
```

I'm getting a message that the action failed with no other info

Comment: Try `git mv utils tmp; git mv tmp Utils`

Comment: Are you on Windows? Which version of git are you using? What is the exact message you got?

Comment: @SebDieBln - Windows, git ver 2.26.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+case+sensitive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename the folder to something else first, then rename it to your expected name:

```
git mv utils tmp
git mv tmp Utils
```

Comment: I finally understand - this worked!

Comment: Suppose you are just changing case sensitive like: **utils to Utils**
Then first rename as **utils** as **temp**, and from **temp** to **Utils**

**Note:-** Don't forgot to mention path from root like- packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/

    git mv packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/Configure packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/temp

    git mv packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/temp packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/configure

Comment: Say you have an invisible folder on windows invisible in the sense that that casing of the folder isnt on windows, how do you fix that, only git is aware of it as the correct casing you want ALSO exists and is the only thing windows knows of. How to fix on git?

Comment: @Morgeth888 I can't follow your sentence. Do you have an example? What is an "invisible folder"? `git mv` will move the file in the index, so you can do that on Windows as well.

Comment: @knittl I got myself in a weird situation somehow, it involved git config core.ignorecase being true. Somehow on git there was both Something/thing.cs and SomeThing/thing.cs and of course windows only has one the correct one Something/thing.cs. I fixed it by deleting the wrong one manually on git without windows involved.

Comment: But that caused some issues when I pulled that update, it deleted the correct files too lol. But everything was ok after a git reset --hard